# Python 3.3 IndexError doesn't make sense

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in py3.3, looks like

```
[ # big container

  [ # month container

    ['date string', 'temp'],['date string', 'temp'] #dates in month

  ], #close month container

  [ # next month container

    ['date string', 'temp'], ['date string', 'temp']

  ]

]
```

Here is my code:

```
dailyDict = []
dailyRow = []
compareStation = 'myfile.csv'
with open(compareStation, newline='\n') as csvfile:
            station = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
            for row in station:
                if 1stDayOfMonthCondition:
                    dailyDict.append(dailyRow)
                    dailyRow = []
                    dailyRow.append(row)
                else:
                    dailyRow.append(row)

for month in dailyDict:
        print(month[1])
```

this gives me an IndexError, list index out of range.
However, when I run `print(month)` I get each month printed out just fine.

And when I set the printed month as a variable, say, `x`, in the shell, I can `print(x[1])` just fine. But `print(month[1])` still fails. Very confused.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get from printing `month`?

Comment: `dailyDict = []`! And that's why you shouldn't write the type of the object in the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The index list starts at 0 not 1 so you should try `print(month[0])`to see if you get any thing that way